# C++: Local typedef returned by a private method

Tags: c++, return-value, typedef, private

The code below isn't correct and I understand why, `get_point` returns a value whose type is unknown outside the class:

```
class C {
    typedef std::pair<double, double> Point;
 public:
    Point get_point() const;
};

Point C::get_point() const {
    [...]
}
```

But why isn't the code below correct? The local type isn't used outside the class!

```
class C {
    typedef std::pair<double, double> Point;
 private:
    Point get_point() const;
};

Point C::get_point() const {
    [...]
}
```

When we use `C::` we should be inside the class, so we should be able to use `Point`!

Comment: What do you mean by "isn't correct"? [It compiles just fine](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0a8b042d178aa085).

Comment: Ok, I simplify too much, I am editing.

Comment: The type's name is `C::Point`.

Comment: _"When we use C:: we should be inside the class, so we should be able to use Point !"_. Inside the function, yes, but the function definition is still in the global scope. If you define the function inside the class your code will work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a valid code. Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

class C 
{
    typedef std::pair<double, double> Point;
    Point p { 10.10, 20.20 };
 public:
    Point get_point() const;
};

C::Point C::get_point() const { return p; }

int main() 
{
    C c;

    auto p = c.get_point();

    std::cout << p.first << ' ' << p.second << std::endl;

    std::pair<double, double> p2 = c.get_point();

    std::cout << p2.first << ' ' << p2.second << std::endl;
}
```

The program output is

```
10.1 20.2
10.1 20.2
```

You may not only use name `C::Point` that is an alias for type `std::pair<double, double>`.

As for this code

```
class C {
    typedef std::pair<double, double> Point;
 private:
    Point get_point() const;
};

Point C::get_point() const {
    [...]
}
```

then you have to write

```
C::Point C::get_point() const {
```

An unqualified name used as the return type of a class member function defined outside the class definition is searched in the scope where the class is defined. And there is no name Point. You have to use a qualified name.

Answer (score 2):

The definition of the function `C::get_point()` is in the global scope and `Point` isn't, so you'll have to specify where `Point` is located. If you move the definition into the class you don't have to specify the scope of the typedef (`C::`) when using `Point`:

```
class C {
    typedef std::pair<double, double> Point;
public:
    Point get_point() const {
        return Point( 1.0, 2.0 );
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

As a brief answer to the question (detailed in the other answers), in the definition of;

```
Point C::get_point() const {
  //...
}
```

Needs to be;

```
C::Point C::get_point() const {
  //...
}
```

Such that the `Point` in the scope of `C` is found.

**It is worth noting**, that if the `typedef` is private, the name of the type (being `Point`) can't be used outside of the class. Client code will either need to use `auto` (or otherwise specify the type).

As per the following sample;

```
class C {
    typedef std::pair<double, double> Point;
public:
    Point get_point() const;
};

C::Point C::get_point() const {
    return Point(); // dummy code to compile sample
}

int main()
{
    C c;
    //C::Point a = c.get_point(); // fails to compile (would compile if Point typedef was public
    auto a = c.get_point(); // compiles
}
```